# Error while initializing properties from GitHub project

Tags: swift, github, frameworks

I loaded a GitHub project as a Package Dependency with this link https://github.com/batoulapps/adhan-swift and as I'm trying to follow the guideline to initialise properties I have some issues.

When I import "Adhan" to initialise PrayerTimes and load these properties:

```
let cal = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
let date = cal.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
```

I get this error: **Cannot use instance member 'cal' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available**

I know I can use a computed property to fix that but what about this then:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .medium
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/New_York")!
```

Answer (score 1):

try to make :

let cal = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)

lazy var date = cal.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())

Comment: That works for "cal" but how can I solve the "formatter.timeStyle" property?